# two sample z test in r

Tags: r, z-test

I am dealing with a dataset like this below

```
 Wt        Group       Weight
 28.29      1          0.87
 38.28      1          0.56
 31.98      2          0.58
 29.12      2          0.62
 34.45      2          0.25
 19.23      1          0.12
 .          .          .
 .          .          .
 .          .          .
 30.12      2          0.49
```

A reproducible dataset might be `data("sleep")`. I am looking for some functions that can perform two sample z.test with the weights. I could do this manually buy calculating the mean of Wt in Group1 and mean of Wt in Group2, std.dev of Wt in Group1 , std.dev of Wt in Group2  and so on but I am looking for functions that can do the same efficiently.

Something like `z.test(Wt ~ Group, data = df, weight = Weight)`

Any advise or suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure. New things are added to R daily. But I think $\nexists.$

Comment: @BruceET,  I agree